# Change default terminal emulator Fedora 33

Tags: terminal, fedora, gnome

I'm trying to change the default terminal in Fedora 33 so if I click "Open in Terminal" from the Nautilus context menu it opens with kitty instead of gnome-terminal (along with any other terminal emulator defaults). What I've tried so far has been:
`update-alternatives`: No x-terminal-emulator like Debian-based distros, so no luck there.
symlinking `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` to `/usr/bin/kitty` seemed to have no effect.

Comment: See related thread: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/338

Comment: So I gather there is no way to achieve this functionality right now?